# Random integer in a given weighted range

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've build a generator returning a random integer in a given, weighted range, but I'm not that happy with how it looks:

```
from random import choices, randrange

def gen_ranged_weighted_value(ranges, weights):
    while True:
        yield randrange(
           *choices(ranges, weights)[0]
        )
```

Is there a built in function for this? Can I write this one better? I wouldn't want to use numpy for such a a simple task.

Also, is there an alternative for `random.choices` here? I would like to build a version working with Python 2.7.x

usage example:

```
foo = gen_ranged_weighted_value([(18,22),(101,201)], [0.98, 0.02])

for a in range(10):
    print(next(foo))
```

Comment: So it's only about the "look"? Efficiency is irrelevant?

Comment: @StefanPochmann The efficiency is by all means important. All optimizations are really welcome. I would like to keep it as basic as possible, but I'm quite open to compare the results.

Comment: Then I suggest you take the source code of `random.choices` and adapt it.

Comment: How large are the ranges? Is it reasonable to represent their union as a list, and use that as the population argument to `choices`?

Comment: Please add an example usage (with `ranges` and `weights`) so we can easily try running this ourselves.

Comment: @MarkDickinson 
@StefanPochmann `ranges` is going to be a list of tupples with quite small ints `ranges = [(18,22),(101,201)]` and `weights` is going to be a list of floats `weights = [0.98, 0.02]`